# How do you run through the entire JSON file, while filtering out specific values & strings from code behind?

Tags: c#, json

may i know how do you run through the entire JSON file and during the process, filter out specific values and strings, such as db_table_name? from code - behind

Here is an example of a JSON file

```
d={"db_table_name":"form_for_hub_trooper_in_store_feedback_form_20160829174321","Date of Audit":"2017-04-27"}
```

Comment: What do you mean by filter out? You want to remove specific values from JSON file?

Comment: No, i am trying to get the db_table_name out so that i can create a database table for it

Answer (score 1):

**test.json** file:

```
{
  "db_table_name": "from_for_bub_trooper_in_store_feedback_from_20160829174321",
  "Date of Audit": "2017-04-27"
}
```

You may simply use `Newtonsoft.Json`. Working code is below:

```
string jsonText = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "test.json");
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(jsonText))
    {
       string json = r.ReadToEnd();
       JObject token = JObject.Parse(json);
       string dbTable = token.SelectToken("db_table_name").ToString();
    }
```

If you want to access json dynamically by condition:

```
string jsonText = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "test.json");
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(jsonText))
        {
            string json = r.ReadToEnd();
            dynamic dynamicJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
            foreach (var item in dynamicJson)
            {
                if (item.Name == "db_table_name")
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
                if (item.Name == "Date of Audit")
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: using this method, how do i read through the entire JSON data? like say the JSON file has 10 values. How am i supposed to filter out the `db_table_name`(for database table creation) and  `Date_of_Audit`(for the column name)?

Comment: @Wasd I have modified my answer. I think here is what you want now.

Comment: is it possible to just filter out the `db_table_name`? as for the rest of the JSON data, i would like to just retrieve them normally.

Comment: Have you run my code on your local? Json is sort of key/value structure. As the code demonstrates above,you can achieve it using `string dbTable = token.SelectToken("db_table_name").ToString();`. This line of code retrieve the value of `db_table_name`.

Comment: Ok, i get that. However, what if i need to have `Date of Audit ` as my column name and the value of it as the data?

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    string d = "{'db_table_name':'form_for_hub_trooper_in_store_feedback_form_20160829174321','Date of Audit':'2017-04-27'}";
    var obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(d);
    Console.WriteLine($"Table Name = {(obj["db_table_name"])}");
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it using `for-each` statement?

Comment: Where is foreach in this ?

Comment: `dynamic result =(myString);
        foreach(var x in myString)
        {

        }`